# How to show IP as Text in HTML using JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the following script in my HTML, however I get a Question mark instead of the actual IP:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var myButton = document.getElementById("clickButton");
    var myText = document.getElementById("helloText");

    myButton.addEventListener('click A', doSomething(), false);

    function doSomething(json) {

        myText.textContent = (json.ip);
    }

    function getIP(json) {
        return json.ip;
    }

</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP">
</script>
```

Comment: You are using getIP function twice. How poor this code is.

Comment: My Javascript knowledge is rusty, but `'click A'` should be just `'click'` instead. And the object passed to `doSomething()` will be a `MouseEvent` object, not a JSON object. You would need to update `myText.textContent` inside of `getIP()` only. And if you want to trigger a new ipify request dynamically in a button click event, you have to inject `script` tags into the browser DOM to trigger a new download of the ipify script each time. Otherwise, run the script once and cache the result, then have the button click event do whatever it needs with that cached value each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `doSomething` doesn't receive the JSON as an argument. You need `getIP` to put the returned IP into a global variable, and then `doSomething` can display it.

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById("clickButton");
var myText = document.getElementById("helloText");

myButton.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

function doSomething() {
  myText.textContent = IP;
}
```

```html
<script type="application/javascript">
  var IP;

  function getIP(json) {
    IP = json.ip;
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP">
</script>
<button id="clickButton">Show IP</button>
<div id="helloText"></div>
```

Also, the second argument to `addEventListener` should just be the function name, not a call to the function. And the first argument should just be the name of the event. There's no `click A` event, just `click`.

Answer (score 2):

The function `getIP()` gets called when the `//api.ipify.org` script is loaded. Your `getIP()` function just returns the ip address. Other than that it does not do anything. Try doing something like this:

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
var getIP = function(json) {
  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = json.ip;
}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP">
</script>
```